# Parallel electric and magnetic field in traveling wave

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Can we have elctromagnetic waves which are characterized by parallel electric and magnetic field $\vec{E} || \vec{B}$ ? I am not talking here about free space, but maybe some kind of materials or waveguides or something else.

Comment: The expression for the Poynting vector $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}$ indicates that if the fields are parallel, the radiated energy is zero ...

Comment: Yes (in theory). This can be seen from two angles:

1) If we have a waveguide made of "perfect" ferromagnetic metal, then E//B locally at the surface.

2) Consider the Lorentz transformation. If E and B are not perpendicular, then there exists an inertial frame where they are parallel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_electromagnetic_fields#Invariants).

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to experimentally align those two vectors (by means of light of course)?

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic waves travelling in [chiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(electromagnetism)) media will have some parallel component of their electric and magnetic fields, although they are usually not exactly parallel. The quantity $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}$ is proportional to the [helicity of light](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.83.021803), which basically tells you how close the beam is to having left or right-handed circular polarisation.

[Tang and Cohen](http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.104.163901) introduced the term "super chiral" to describe situations where this helicity is maximized (relative to the power density). Basically it involves creating standing waves with circularly polarised beams.

Answer (score 0):

I've already provided two possibilities in the comment above, and now I'm expanding my answer because I realize that this is achievable even in free space (though by a mathematical trick instead of physical reasons):

Imagine two identical planewaves except that they have opposite wave vector and polarization, then the E and B fields are parallel where the phases match.

For the sake of completeness, my previous comment is copied below:

Yes (in theory). This can be seen from two angles: 1) If we have a waveguide made of "perfect" ferromagnetic metal, then E//B locally at the surface. 2) Consider the Lorentz transformation. If E and B are not perpendicular, then there exists an inertial frame where they are parallel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_electromagnetic_fields#Invariants